# Switch statements and percentages

Tags: java

How do I multiply a percentage and a user input number in a switch statement? I'm making a program that takes a number the user inputs and alters it in various ways but I'm stuck on the percentages part.

```
int userChoice; //The user's choice from the menu.

double percentCurve = .1; //A 10% increase to the user's grade the user chooses by selecting option 2.

int userExtraPercent; //The percentage the user chooses to add to their grade by choosing option 4.
        userChoice = keyboard.nextInt ();

switch( userChoice) {

case 2:
System.out.println("Curve applied: " + percentCurve);
double adjustedGradeTwo = userGrade * percentCurve;
                System.out.println("Adjusted grade: " + adjustedGradeTwo);
                break;
                //Takes user's grade and adds 10 percent.

case 4:
System.out.println("Enter the percentage of the curve: "); 
userExtraPercent = keyboard.nextInt ();
System.out.println("Curve applied: " + userExtraPercent + "%"); 

int adjustedGradeFour = userGrade * userExtraPercent;
System.out.println("Adjusted grade: " + adjustedGradeFour); 
break;
//Adds a percentage chosen by the user to their initial grade.
}
```

There are three other possible choices in my switch statement but I edited those out since those are working and even I'm getting confused and I wrote the bloody thing. XD

Anyway, what I need to figure out is how to take the user's number, convert it to a percent, multiply it by the user's grade and display the result to the user. IE, user has a grade of 85, they want an extra 12%, my program gives them a grade of 95.2.

Comment: You could use `Scanner.nextDouble` to ask for a percentage, then just divide it by 100 before you multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for case 4:

```
System.out.println("Enter the percentage of the curve: "); 
double userExtraPercent = keyboard.nextDouble();

double adjustedGradeFour = userGrade + (userGrade * (userExtraPercent / 100.0));
System.out.println("Curve applied: " + userExtraPercent + "%"); 
System.out.println("Adjusted grade: " + adjustedGradeFour);
```

Use `Scanner.nextDouble`, then just divide it by 100 (assuming they're entering 12 for 12 percent).